# javascript error in Firefox windows 7, working in other browsers an OS

Tags: javascript, php

Hi this code seems to work fine in all browsers, just firefox in windows 7, is giving this issue, in firefox windows 8 (firefox 28,29) its ok. so i dont get it

This is a page i did not write, but im fixing some issues, this particular error its out of my knowledge wich is very basic yet.

So firefox gives this error

ReferenceError: autoExpire is not defined.

my first tought was to define var autoExpire; in javascript. But then looking at code there is a function autoExpire () is this the issue? why is working in other browsers, why is not working on windows 7?

Hope you can help me , here is the code.

```
    if(Get_Cookie('<?php echo COOKIE_REMEMBER_ME;?>') ==0)
    {
        if(Get_Cookie('<?php echo COOKIE_LOGINID;?>'))
        var aexp=setInterval(autoExpire,10000);


        if(!autocount)
        {
            var autocount;
            autocount=0;
        }

        function autoExpire()
        {
            autocount=autocount+1;
            if(autocount > parseInt(<?php echo COOKIE_EXPIRY_TIME*6;?>))
            {
                clearInterval(aexp);
                window.location.href='<?php echo $this->make_base_url("user/logout/a");?>';
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT

Yes, this function is inside

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    }
```

With other functions to, the only error i can see is this thats why i just copy the function with error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the function before it's defined.

Try this.

```
if (Get_Cookie('<?php echo COOKIE_REMEMBER_ME;?>') == 0) {
    if (Get_Cookie('<?php echo COOKIE_LOGINID;?>'))

    function autoExpire() {
        autocount = autocount + 1;
        if (autocount > parseInt( <? php echo COOKIE_EXPIRY_TIME * 6; ?> )) {
            clearInterval(aexp);
            window.location.href = '<?php echo $this->make_base_url("user/logout/a");?   >';
        }
    }

    var aexp = setInterval(autoExpire, 10000);

    if (!autocount) {
        var autocount;
        autocount = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do wrap all in document.ready i just edit, i will try your solution

Comment: But you where right document.ready is not enough , it does matter the order, Your solution Reordering code, fix this . =) great.

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's inside a DOM ready event handler…  he is still calling the function before it's defined.

Comment: The strange stuff even when you are rigth sparky is that only Firefox drop the error, the script was working as charm on all other browsers, XD.